# Strange behavior using not exists and not in queries with postgres and mysql foreign data wrapper

Tags: mysql, postgresql, exists, notin

I'm experimenting with some MD5 hashing and select queries and came across some strange behavior I can't explain.

I have foreign tables on an MySQL server with the following structures (using mysql_fdw extension):

```
CREATE TABLE `ANT_Tags` (
  `TmStamp` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000',
  `RecNum` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TagLoc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InStringTag` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TmStamp`,`RecNum`)
)

CREATE TABLE `CRU_Tags` (
  `TmStamp` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000',
  `RecNum` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Tag` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TmStamp`,`RecNum`)
)
```

The only difference between the tables is one table has tagloc (int) and instringtag (text) and the second just has tag(text).  On the Postgres server, I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.processed_tags
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('processed_tags_id_seq'::regclass),
    insert_dt timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    lndb_table character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    md5_hash character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT processed_tags_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I am using a CTE statement to query and process records from these tables (grab information, write it to another table and log what has been processed via the hash) when I was having some performance issues. Doing some investigating, I ran into a strange issue with using not in versus not exists. I've narrowed it down to the select statement.

A little background:  I was referring to this stackoverflow for performance tuning queries:  [PostgreSQL query is slow when using NOT IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996002/postgresql-query-is-slow-when-using-not-in)

Here is the strange behavior I am hoping someone can explain.  This query ran on the first table above, runs forever (well not sure how long, I canceled it after 10-15 minutes):

```
        select 
            now(),
            'ant_tags' as lndb_table, 
            MD5(MD5(to_char(tmstamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) || MD5(recnum::text) || MD5('ant_tags')) as md5_hash, 
            tmstamp, 
            recnum, 
            tagloc,
            instringtag
        from ant_tags 
        where tmstamp > '2009-01-01' and tmstamp <= now()
        and MD5(MD5(to_char(tmstamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) || MD5(recnum::text) || MD5('ant_tags'))
        not in (select md5_hash from processed_tags where lndb_table = 'ant_tags')
```

Using the hints from the stackoverflow article above, I changed it to:

```
            select 
                now(),
                'ant_tags' as lndb_table, 
                MD5(MD5(to_char(tmstamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) || MD5(recnum::text) || MD5('ant_tags')) as md5_hash, 
                tmstamp, 
                recnum, 
                instringtag
            from ant_tags 
                and not exists (
                select 1
                from processed_tags
                where lndb_table = 'ant_tags' and md5_hash = MD5(MD5(to_char(tmstamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) || MD5(recnum::text) || MD5('ant_tags'))
)
```

This query runs fast and returns within seconds.

The strangeness is if I run the same queries on the other table, replacing tag for tagloc and instringtag in the select columns, I have the exact opposite issue.  The not exists query takes forever and the not in query returns in seconds.

```
select 
    ...
    tag
```

versus

```
select 
    ...
    tagloc,
    instringtag
```

I have other tables with the same structures where I am seeing the same results.  The tables with tagloc and instringtag work well using *not exists* but not with *not in* and the second table structure works well with *not in* and is slow with *not exists*.

Notes: 
There are approximately 100K row being selected/processed.

example instringtag: 01 03 01/02/2018 23:11:51.200 3E7.0000001D03

example tag: TAG: 01 03 01/02/2018 23:11:51.200 3E7.0000001D03

(the only real difference being the "TAG:")

Comment: How many of each type of thing are there? A huge list takes a huge amount of time, short lists are faster. I would advise against using `in` and `not in` around query results - use joins instead.

Comment: @Bohemian: about 100K rows per each.  Joins may work, but my real question is why is there a difference between not in and not exists for two almost identical tables.